# Does NoSqlEntityManager.put update if id is the same?

Tags: playorm

I have a mapped entity in playOrm which has a lot of attributes, like birthDate, categories, etc.

Suppose I used NoSqlEntityManager.put to save this entity in Cassandra in the first time. I wrote the following:

```
NoSqlEntityManager em =...;
Entity e = new Entity();
entity.id = 123
entity.birthDate = 20121212
em.put(e);
```

After that, some time later, I do the following:

```
NoSqlEntityManager em =...;
Entity e = new Entity();
entity.id = 123
entity.categories = {"cat1", "cat2", "cat3"};
em.put(e);
```

What will happen in Cassandra? A new entity will be created? Or the old one will be updated (desirable)?
If it is updated, will birthDate be erased in my second write? (non-desirable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

em.put(e, false); can be used to update but it reads in a value mostly because it has to figure out if indices have changed/been modified.

If you do em.put(e), then birthDate in the database will be changed to null.

This is interesting though.  I wonder if we should have a flag on each field in an entity to say null will not be written to the database like in your case.  IF we do have a @Column(nullsWritten=false), the question then becomes if you actually want to write null in a special case, how would you write null in that case?  Any ideas?

Do you have any fields with @NoSqlIndexable in the Entity above?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I think the attribute in the field would be an excelent start.

Comment: I don't have for now a NoSqlIndexable in this entity, but will have in the future for sure

Comment: Any final solution for this would involve passing something in the put operations to describe which fields should be updated and which ones should not, if needed in an extreme case.  However, for my case, I think the solution you gave using em.put(e, false) will be enough. Thanks a lot, BTW :D

Comment: add a github issue for the other one if you like as well.  I still have work to do on finishing the playframework plugin that replaces the old way of doing it from an existing ticket(hopefully will finish this week)

Comment: Make sure you add @NoSqlIndexable early on for "at least" one field as the command line tool can use that to select *.  Without it, a full map/reduce would be needed.